# Массивы, подсчет слов, подсчет строк

Tags: c

Зачем в программе подсчета цифр, символов, пустого пространства и остальных символов мы пишем `++ndigit`?

Зачем вообще делать это `++`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* подсчет цифр, символов-разделителей и прочих символов */
main()
{
   int с, i, nwhite, nother;
   int ndigit[10];

   nwhite = nother = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
          ndigit[i]= 0;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
         if (c >= '0' && с <= '9' )
              ++ndigit[c - '0' ];
    else if (c == ' ' || с == '\n' || с == '\t')
           ++nwhite;
    else
            ++nother;
    printf ("цифры =");
    for (i=0; i < 10; ++i)
          printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf (", символы-разделители = %d, прочие = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: @Иван Братчиков, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто. ndigit - это массив, который хранит количество цифр. Если текущий символ - цифра (в предыдущей строке условие), то нужно ее учесть. Разберем строку

```
++ndigit[c - '0' ];
```

По кусочкам.

В переменной `c` хранится текущая цифра (это гарантировано так из-за условия). В си (да и в других языках) все символы имеют свой код ([аски код](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). И самое интересное - они все упорядоченные. У нуля код 48, у единицы - 49, у девятки - 57. Код `c - '0'` - это очень известный трюк, который преобразовывает аски код в число. То есть, символу '7' будет соответствовать число 7.

Два плюса - это операция увеличения на единицу.

Следовательно, код `++ndigit[c - '0' ];` можно записать `так ndigit[текущая_цифра] = ndigit[текущая_цифра]+1`.

После прохода всей строки в массиве ndigit собирается количество цифр с разбивкой по каждой цифре.

Comment: а почему ndigit[текущая_цифра]+1 , зачем прибавлять +1?

Comment: Э... Ну увеличение `nwhite` на 1 при встрече пробельного символа же не удивляет? Вот здесь то же самое. `ndigits[0]` содержит количество символов '0' (изначально - ни одного), встречаем ноль - увеличиваем счётчик на 1. В `ndigits[1]` хранится количество символов '1', поступаем аналогично, и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо! И еще одно . А как определить какое долдно быть число в фигурных скобках масива(ndigit[10])? как вообще определить когда какой символ ставить в эти фигурные скобки?

Comment: http://cpp.6te.net/index.php/lessons/58-lesson6

http://c-book-help.narod.ru/box/page10.html

Answer (score 1):

Постинкремент смотрелся бы логичней, конечно:

```
ndigit[c-'0']++;
```

> зачем вообще делать это ++

По условию неочевидно, что нужно считать количество разных цифр. Для подсчёта цифр **всего** достаточно было бы одной переменной. Но в коде считается сколько **разных** цифр, для этого и заводится массив `ndigit` (в первом элементе накапливается количество нолей, во втором - количество единиц и т.д.).